# Use models in template django 3

Tags: python, django

I want to show the list of items in `MyModel`.

I used to use php framework , not good for python yet.

I googled around and search for best practices, but I cant find the explanation for Django 3.

Does anyone help?

my code is like this.

in `views.py`

```
mymodels = MyModel.objects.all()

data = {
    'mymodels' : mymodels
}
return render(request, 'myapp/index.html',data)
```

in `myapp/index.html`

```
{% for m in mymodels %}
{{m.id}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: {{ m.field_name }} will display your fields

Comment: Your code looks like it will work to display a list of IDs. Does it do that?

Comment: Sorry it is my typo....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are doing the right way in your `html` file, that's how it goes...

```
{% for item in mymodels %}
  <h2>{{ item.field_name }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```